# SimpleDateFormat.format() not returning correct formatted date string

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a date into "MMMMM yy" format. However, when I run the code it doesn't return the fully formatted date.

Here is the code

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // "Mon Jun 10 09:50:06 HST 2019"
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM yy", Locale.US);
String formatDate = format.format(date); // "J 19"
System.out.println(formatDate);
```

Let's say the inputted date is `"Mon Jun 10 09:50:06 HST 2019"` and the resulting output is `"J 19"` when I want it to be `"June 19"`. I feel like I'm missing something simple here but can't figure out what.

Comment: You should use LocalDate

Comment: @AnishB. Question is tagged `android`, so OP probably can't, if they want to support old phones.

Comment: Try 4 M's instead of 5, since [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) says that 3 M's is short form and 4 M's is long form, and you want the long form. Don't know why you're using 5 M's.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. The classes you want are `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MMMMM` corresponds to the "tiny" month format. Use four-letter `MMMM` format for the full month name.

References:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#1426

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Documentation for SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat) :

> Stand-Alone Month - Use one or two for the numerical month, three for
>   the abbreviation, four for the full (wide) name, or 5 for the narrow
>   name. With two ("LL"), the month number is zero-padded if necessary
>   (e.g. "08").

The code should be :

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yy", Locale.US);
String formatDate = format.format(date); 
System.out.println(formatDate);
```

Output :

```
June 19
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM uu", Locale.US);
    YearMonth thisMonth = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("America/Louisville"));
    String formatDate = thisMonth.format(monthFormatter);
    System.out.println(formatDate);
```

When I ran this snippet just now, the output was:

> June 19

I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The date-time classes that you used, `Calendar` and in particular `SimpleDateFormat`, were always poorly designed and are long outdated.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried your code and it's working as expected. I got June 19 as a result. As Andreas already commented, you can remove one M in your SimpleDateFormat because the pattern letters with length more than 3 will be in full form.

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.
>
> Text: For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters.

so your SimpleDateFormat pattern will be:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yy", Locale.US);
```